# how to check if a list of sub-strings is in a list (python)

Tags: python, string, list, csv, substring

I have a list of strings called `keywords`:

`keywords = ["123", "hello there"]`

I want to see if any of these strings are in this list `strArr`:

`strArr = ["123", "hello there", "another"]`

I've tried this:

```
if all (keyword in strArr for keyword in keywords):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

It works and returns true if I have the full string, but fails when I try to find a sub-string like so:

`keywords = ["123", "hello"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if each keyword is **in** any of the items in **strArr**:

```
print( all ( any( (keyword in strItem for strItem in strArr) ) for keyword in keywords ))
```

Note: if you are checking a condition and printing the result you could just print the condition itself.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you have groups of things and you are testing membership/intersection etc, you should think about using `sets`. It is so much easier after you get started.

See the following example:

```
In [46]: keywords = {"123", "hello there"}                                                  
In [47]: strArr = {"123", "hello there", "another"}                                         
In [48]: keywords & strArr   # intersection                                                               
Out[48]: {'123', 'hello there'}
In [49]: keywords.issubset(strArr)                                                          
Out[49]: True
In [50]: if (keywords & strArr):  # do something
```

In the last line, if the `intersection` has anything in it, the value will be `True`, else it will be `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have already answered this question. Since I tried it, I will post my answer.

```
print ([i for i in strArr if any(j in keywords for j in i.split())]) # Outer For loop: "i for i in strArr", Inner For Loop with If any condition(): "if any(j in keywords for j in i.split())"
```

I hope this counts. :)